# How to run FLV videos in iphone apps code?

Tags: iphone, video, flv

How to add and run FLV videos in iphone apps code? Is there any conversion code for this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to convert your videos to .mp4 files, Flash, FLVs included, don't work on iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, FLV is Flash video, and iOS doesn't support Flash at all. You need to convert it to a format the iPhone understands - mp4, mov, etc. You can use ffmpeg to do it yourself, or have a service like Zencoder handle it.